# SignalR send All include method

Tags: c#, signalr

When I use SignalR to implement a pushing service, I find `Clients.All()` and `Clients.AllExcept()` functions, but I need a function like `Clients.Some()`. I can describe my case here.

There is a message needed to be sent to several users, we called **receivers**, and the online user list, we called **onlineusers**. Some online users maybe not exist in the message receivers, I need exclude these users. If I use `AllExcept()`, how can I get the excluded users from the two sets? If I use a loop while to get the set, it seems not benefit to performance. Could some one make any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at groups?

Comment: Yes, groups is the way to go about this. Since groups persist, there isn't a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using groups to manage the users.

A simple example to join/leave groups and send a message to given group would be:

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients in group
        Clients.Group("recievers").addMessage("Group Message " + message);
    }
}
```

more info here: [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#singleusergroups)

Comment: In my case, there is no fixed group. The users are dynamicaly grouped by the pushing message. If I use group function, should I make the online users to join a group one by one, and then remove the group memebers after published the message? thanks.

Comment: If they would only be eligible for one message, then they could be removed from the group after the message is sent.

Comment: Yes, every message would be sent to a special dynamic group in every time. So I think it's better that if there is a Clients.Some() function, and I dont need to maintain a Group object every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use groups and the exclusion parameter to send to subsections of groups.

Aka lets say we have the following users in group "Foo": "cidA", "cidB", "cidC"

We can now send to a subsection of "Foo" via the following:

```
string[] invalidConnectionIds = getMyInvalidConnectionIds(); // Lets say it returns ["cidC"]
Clients.Group("Foo", invalidConnectionIds); // Sends to "cidA" and "cidB"
```

Where `getMyInvalidConnectionIds` determines what connection ID's do not meet the wanted criteria.  This way you get the benefit of providing filters and still maintain the performance benefits of groups.

Comment: Every message would be sent to a special dynamic group in every time. So I think it's better that if there is a Clients.Some() function, and I dont need to maintain a Group object every time. thanks